# my code doesn't look the way I want

Tags: javascript

here is a code I have written. it works fine but it has a small problem.
when I push the zoom button to zoom on a picture. picture becomes bigger and covers the buttons. how can I fix this problem?(i want my pictures grow when I push the zoom button but I don't want them to cover the button)

```js
var images = document.querySelectorAll('img.images');
var displayCount = 0;
var hideCount = 0;
document.getElementById('display').onclick = function() {
  if (hideCount < images.length) {
    images[hideCount].style.display = 'none';
    zoomOut(images[hideCount]);
    hideCount++;
  } else {
    images[displayCount].style.display = 'block';
    zoomOut(images[displayCount]);
    displayCount++;
    if (displayCount === images.length) {
      displayCount = 0;
      hideCount = 0;
    }
  }
}
document.getElementById('zoombtn').onclick = function() {
  if (hideCount > 0) {
    images[hideCount - 1].style.display = 'block';
    zoomIn(images[hideCount - 1]);
    hideCount--;
  } else {
    images[11].style.display = 'block';
    zoomIn(images[11]);
  }
}

function zoomIn(zElement) {
  var element = document.getElementById(zElement.id);
  element.style.transform = "scale(2)";
  //element.style.width *= 2;
}

function zoomOut(zElement) {
  var element = document.getElementById(zElement.id);
  element.style.transform = "scale(1)";
}
```

```css
.botton {
  height: 30px;
  width: 405px;
}

.table {
  margin-left: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

h3 {
  margin-left: 325px;
}

h4 {
  margin-left: 290px;
}
```

```html
<button class="botton" ; id="display" ;>Display</button>
<button class="botton" ; id="zoombtn" ;>Zoom</button>
<br></br>
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img SRC="blfy.gif" ALT="Butterflies" id="image-1" class="images" height="200" width="200" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <img SRC="eye.gif" ALT="Eye" id="image-2" class="images" height="200" width="200" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <img SRC="wave.gif" ALT="Wave" id="image-3" class="images" height="200" width="200" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <IMG SRC="jungle.gif" ALT="Jungle" id="image-4" class="images" height="200" width="200" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <IMG SRC="bridge.gif" ALT="Bridge" id="image-5" class="images" height="200" width="200" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <IMG SRC="duck.gif" ALT="Duck" id="image-6" class="images" height="200" width="200" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <IMG SRC="egg.gif" ALT="Eggs" id="image-7" class="images" height="200" width="200" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <IMG SRC="aurora.gif" ALT="Aurora" id="image-8" class="images" height="200" width="200" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <IMG SRC="it.gif" ALT="Technology" id="image-9" class="images" height="200" width="200" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <IMG SRC="hill.gif" ALT="Hills" id="image-10" class="images" height="200" width="200" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <IMG SRC="string.gif" ALT="strings" id="image-11" class="images" height="200" width="200" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <IMG SRC="vegi.gif" ALT="vegetables" id="image-12" class="images" height="200" width="200" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using z-index

See [z-index example](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)

```
.botton {
  height: 30px;
  width: 405px;
  z-index: 999;
  background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
```